# Does setting the same program with gl.useProgram twice in a row make a notable performance impact?

Tags: webgl

I have a 2D game I've been working on in webGL, and, with few exceptions, I use one default program for drawing sprites onscreen. I call `gl.useProgram` once, on initialization, and if I ever need to use a different program, I reset the program to the default when I'm done.

However, I see examples where others call gl.useProgram every time they draw, and therefore at least once on every frame, or possibly as many times as there are quads to be rendered, in a worst-case scenario.

For the sake of peace of mind, I'd like to use `gl.useProgram` for every draw call, so I always know exactly which program is being used, but only if it's still relatively efficient to do so.

My question is, if you use `gl.useProgram` to set the program to the program already in use, is there a performance impact, or does webGL/javascript essentially "know" that the program remains unchanged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if you use gl.useProgram to set the program to the program already in use, is there a performance impact

Doing more work than less always has some impact. The question I think you're really asking is it too much impact. Only you can tell. I suspect it's tiny but how about just trying it and seeing if you notice a difference?

> does webGL/javascript essentially "know" that the program remains unchanged?

There's no way to guarantee this is checked. You could look into the source code of every browser and check back every few months to see it didn't change.

But, if you're concerned just check yourself

```
let globalLastProgram = null

function checkedUseProgram(program) {
  if (globalLastProgram !== program) {
    globalLastProgram = program;
    gl.useProgram(program);
  }
}
```

Now call `checkedUseProgram` instead of `gl.useProgram`.

Or if you want wrap `useProgram` itself.

```
WebGLRenderingContext.prototype.useProgram = function(origFn) {
  return function(program) {
    if (this.lastProgram !== program) {
      this.lastProgram = program;
      origFn.call(this, program);
    }
  };
}(WebGLRenderingContext.prototype.useProgram);
```

If you don't like `lastProgram` being on the context you can make a wrapping function

```
function addWrapper(gl) {
  gl.useProgram = function(origFn) {
    let lastProgram;

    return function(program) {
      if (lastProgram !== program) {
        lastProgram = program;
        origFn.call(this, program);
      }
    };
  }(gl.useProgram);
}

addWrapper(gl);
```

Of course all of those will have a tiny impact as well though I suspect it's hard to measure

Comment: imho augmenting the `WebGLContext` instance (or any instance of a built-in class for that matter) should be avoided for the sake of keeping the code concise, otherwise one can not rely on their previous knowledge of how the built-in objects work and always has to check for augmentations before referring to any official doc.

Comment: The immediate follow up of the proposed method of wrapping `useProgram` is to use `ctx.lastProgram` outside of it and then after maybe have a hiatus  or someone new coming in, wondering _"is lastProgram the current program or the one before that, can I set it to actually change the program, why is it not in the webgl spec, where is it coming from?"_

Comment: That answer is about what I expected. I suppose that answers my deeper question of "is this something well-known to those with more experience than myself, but that I was unable to find by googling?". It probably behooves me to simply keep track of which program is currently loaded and continue to update only as needed.

Comment: @LJ "should be avoided for the sake of keeping the code concise". It seems far more concise not to have to tell other users to call your special function. With the non-wrapped version if someone forgets to call `checkedUseProgram` and instead called `gl.useProgram` your program breaks. But whatever, it's all subjective. Do whatever makes you happy. I'm just listing solutions. I agree better to track yourself at a higher level.

Comment: I didn't advise for the other solution either, I'd assume that the OP has some kind of abstraction layer over their "renderables" that could allow for tracking without having some error prone free floating `checkedUseProgram` function. I'm certainly not the only one advising against modification / extension of in-built / native objects, the reason I stated is only one of many and once you start going down that path ... well.

Answer (score 0):

A modern GPU driver applies state changes before issuing a draw command, effectively filtering any in-between changes that have no side effects. So setting the same program several times will unlikely have a serious impact. But setting the same state needlessly results in redundant state change warning in many graphic debuggers. It is considered an undesirable behavior. After you set a program with `gl.UseProgram` it will remain active in the context until replaced with another program or the context is lost. Even deleting the program with `gl.DeleteProgram` doesn't make the currently bound program invalid.